# Change the process receiving stdin in docker container

Tags: docker

I have an image whose ENTRYPOINT must be a definite process (i.e. systemd), but I also need to be able to run a bash shell in order to send commands to the container. This has to be done through the container stdin, but as far as I understand the container stdin is routed to the ENTRYPOINT process. Is there a way to re-route the stdin to another process like a bash shell spawn by a systemd unit?

Comment: Is your virtual machine running an ssh daemon?  You could use normal `ssh root@vm-ip command` to do things there.

Comment: (Normally a Docker container only runs a single process, not a heavy-weight system-management daemon like systemd.  You could run a new container that is only running the process you want to work with and nothing else, and that might better meet your needs.)

Comment: The fact is that a process in the container requires systemd, but I also need to have a shell attached to container's STDIN to let Gitlab CI attach to the container and send the CI commands to the shell to be executed in the container.